# Allow a user to select a folder path in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

What is the best way to allow a user to select a folder path in Notes?

Answer (score 4):

I use this undocumented @formula or Lotus Script function for years and love it:

```
@Prompt(14; ""; "");
```

Allows user to select a filesystem folder. Similar to, but not the same, as...

```
@Prompt([LocalBrowse]; ""; "");
```

This can also be used via

```
Dim uiws As New NotesUIWorkspace
folder = uiws.Prompt(14, {}, {})
```

Credits go to:
http://news4notes.com/web/dokumente/notes_undocumented_formula.html

Contains a list of nice undocumented functions.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Very usefull & short solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for `NotesUIWorkspace.OpenFileDialog()`, this function displays a file dialog with Lotus Script.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that what you are needing is how to select a folder, no a file.

This is what you need [from IBM's Notes and Domino Application Development wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/HowTo_Browse_for_folders)

```
Const BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE = &H00000040
Const BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON = &H00000200
Dim objShell As Variant
Dim objFolder As Variant
Dim objFolderItem As Variant
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select a folder", BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON + BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE, "C:\")
If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    Msgbox objFolderItem.Path 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Help docs:

```
stringArray = notesUIWorkspace.OpenFileDialog(multipleSelection, [title$], [filters$], [initialDirectory$], [initialFile$])
```

Example:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
filenames = ws.OpenFileDialog(True, "Select files to be deleted", "All Files|*.*", "c:\work")
```

Comment: This function calls the file selection dialog box, not folder selection.